# Inserting value conditionally based on another column's value with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to:
Search each value in column S.
If the value = "CA", select the cell in the same row but in column I.
If the value of that cell is <= 93599, select the original cell in column S, and overwrite it with "CS".
If the (column I) cell value is > 93599, select the original cell in column S, and overwrite it with "CN".
Then continue checking the rest of the cells in column S.

```vb
Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim cell As Range
Dim a As String

Set wks = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Addresses")
   
With wks

    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    If LastRow = 1 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
            
    a = "93599"
    
    For Each cell In .Range(.Cells(2, 19), .Cells(LastRw, 19))
    
        If cell = "CA" Then
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, -10).Select
             
            If ActiveCell.Value <= a Then
                ActiveCell.Offset(0, 10).Select
                ActiveCell.Value = "CS"
             
            Else
                ActiveCell.Offset(0, 10).Select
                ActiveCell.Value = "CN"
    
            End If
    
        End If

    Next cell

End With
```

This code returns

> "Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error"

and highlights the `ActiveCell.Offset(0, -10).Select` which suggests that a cell in column S is not selected when it's trying to perform the offset.

Comment: Are the values you're checking against `a` actually strings, or numbers?

Comment: @TimWilliams so they were originally numbers (the values in column I), but I ran Selection.NumberFormat = "00000"  in previous code to convert them to zipcodes. Also, If I change it to Dim a as Integer, I get an overflow.

Comment: `ActiveCell.Offset(0, -10).Select` - you have not activated the cell in Col S before calling this, so if the activecell is left of Col K this will fail as you're trying to select a zero or negative column number

Comment: You've only applied a format to your numbers, so .Value still reads the numeric value.  Integer maxes out at around 32000, so you'd need Long in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the column I values are numeric then comparing them to a string may not be ideal.

```vb
Sub tester()
    Dim cell As Range, a
    
    a = 93599
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Addresses")
        For Each cell In .Range("S2:S" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "S").End(xlUp).Row).Cells
            If cell.Value = "CA" Then
                Select Case cell.EntireRow.Columns("I").Value
                    Case Is <= a: cell.Value = "CS"
                    Case Is > a: cell.Value = "CN"
                End Select
            End If
        Next cell
    End With
End Sub
```

Note you typically never need to activate/select anything when working with ranges.  See:

[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Answer (score 0):

Just a matter of taste and for presenting an alternative in the way it's formatted, here is my answer

```
Public Sub AjustValues()

    ' Set target value
    Dim targetValue As Long
    targetValue = 93599

    ' Get reference to addresses sheet in workbook running the code
    Dim AddrSheet As Worksheet
    Set AddrSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Addresses")
    
    ' Get last row in column A (see that you can refer to the column letter instead of the number)
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = AddrSheet.Cells(AddrSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Exit procedure if last row is 1
    If lastRow = 1 Then Exit Sub
    
    ' Loop through each in column S starting from row 2 ending in last row
    Dim sourceCell As Range
    For Each sourceCell In AddrSheet.Range("S2:S" & lastRow)
        
        ' Check cell value
        If sourceCell.Value = "CA" Then
            
            ' Choose according to the value in column I
            Select Case sourceCell.Offset(0, -10).Value
            Case Is <= targetValue
                sourceCell.Value = "CS"
                
            Case Is > targetValue
                sourceCell.Value = "CN"
            End Select
        End If
        
    Next sourceCell
    

End Sub
```